# How to not replace when preceded with some characters using String's replaceAll

Tags: java, regex, string, replaceall, word-boundary

I need to replace some words in a text, but I need to put conditions in the replacement strategy as follows:

I want to replace *word1* with *word2*:

```
String word1 = "word1";
String word2 = "word2";
```

but I don't want to replace *word1* if it's preceded by *word3* which is:

```
String word3 = "word3."; //with the dot at the ending
```

That is if the text is ***word3.word1*** I don't want to touch it.
But I can't seem to handle that with *word boundaries* using *String*'s `replaceAll` method.

**EDIT:**

And also I don't want to change if word1 has a prefix or suffix of "-" character i.e. ***-word1*** or ***word1-*** or ***-word1-***

Any help would be appreciable.

Comment: If you want to replace *word1* and it is detached than you could use `String.replaceAll(" word1 ", " word2 ")` (note leading and ending whitespaces). Your String `word3.word1` wouldn't be affected. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will give you a hint

```
String str = "word3.word1.word2.word1";
str.replaceAll("word3.word1", "word3.wordX1").replaceAll("word1", "word2").replaceAll("wordX1", "word1");
```

Comment: Defenitely! I mentioned 'wordX1' as some string that can be assumed as never be available within the String list. If can assume, True you can't use this.

Answer (score 5):

Use regular expressions with negative lookbehind: `(?<!word3\\.)word1`

Comment: +1 This works fine. How about if I don't want to replace as well if word1 has suffix or prefix of "-" character i.e. "-word1" or "word1-" or "-word1-"

Answer (score 1):

> I don't want to replace word1 if it's preceded by word3.

You need to use a [negative lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

Unless you want to hard-code the words you probably want to use `Pattern.quote` as well.

Here's some example code:

```
String word1 = "word1";
String word2 = "word2";
String word3 = "word3.";

String regex = String.format("(?<!%s)%s", Pattern.quote(word3),
                                          Pattern.quote(word1));

String input = "aaa word1 bbb word3.word1 ccc";

String result = input.replaceAll(regex, word2);

System.out.println(result);
```

**Output:**

```
aaa word2 bbb word3.word1 ccc
```

(first `word1` is replaced, second `word1` is not replaced since it is preceeded by `word3.`)

Comment: +1 This works fine. How about if I don't want to replace as well if word1 has suffix or prefix of "-" character i.e. "-word1" or "word1-" or "-word1-"

Comment: Have a look at negative lookbehind and negative lookahead.

Answer (score 1):

i m assuming the following scenario

```
String word1 = "word1";
String word2 = "word2";
String word3 = "word3";
String mysentence = "word3.myname.word1";
```

programatically you do like this

```
int word1loc = mysentence.indexOf(word1);
int word2loc = mysentence.indexOf(word2);
int word3loc = mysentence.indexOf(word3);

if (word1loc> word3loc){
mysentence.replaceAll(word1,word2);
}
```

i believe it may help you ...!

Comment: Your call to replaceAll is basically a no-op though, since strings are immutable.

Comment: There might be more than one word1, word2, and word3 in the text, sadly this will not help.